# I Have No Ability to Search at All via Chrome....How Do I "Reinstall" Google?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, search

I'm on an iMac running OSMohave 10.14.16.  Two days ago, I downloaded a Cyber Search virus and used Malwarebytes to clean things up. Since then, I can no longer use the address bar to search for things...when I try, I just get the message, "This site can't be reached."  If I open a new page or tab and physically go to the Google webpage, I can search from there, but of course this isn't optimal.

I've already tried going to "preferences," and choosing Google as the default search engine for the address bar to no avail.  I've also tried resetting Chrome and even throwing it away and downloading again.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Brenda

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I'd been throwing away the "program," but I did a little research, opened the terminal on my computer and also trashed all the preferences, etc.  Then I downloaded a fresh, clean copy of Chrome and away we go!  Now the address bar works as a search bar again.